# PYTEST ERROR VS CODE: PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accesso negato: 'E:\\System Volume Information'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path

Trying to make my tests on VS Code running but I have this error and I don't know how to continue.

Could someone of you know how to fix?
The last run was: pytest -rP

```
C:\Users\emanu\anaconda3real\envs\GenAlgo\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py:311: in from_call
result: Optional[TResult] = func() 
C:\Users\emanu\anaconda3real\envs\GenAlgo\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py:341: in <lambda>
call = CallInfo.from_call(lambda: list(collector.collect()), "collect")
C:\Users\emanu\anaconda3real\envs\GenAlgo\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py:690: in collect
for direntry in visit(str(argpath), self._recurse):
C:\Users\emanu\anaconda3real\envs\GenAlgo\lib\site-packages\_pytest\pathlib.py:606: in visit
yield from visit(entry.path, recurse)
C:\Users\emanu\anaconda3real\envs\GenAlgo\lib\site-packages\_pytest\pathlib.py:591: in visit
for entry in os.scandir(path):
E   PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accesso negato: 'E:\\System Volume Information'
```

Comment: how does `E:\\System Volume Information` end up in your search path

Answer (score 0):

Could you try running the VSCode through `Run as Administrator`?